# Is there an easy way to pass dataframes between R and Python?

Tags: python, r

I am looking for a way to pass dataframes between R and Python other than writing csv files.

I am working on a package in R that I would like to have use Python to handle the more heavy computations.

I am currently using system2, found from this [source](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/10/integrating-python-r-executing-part2.html)

This isn't my program but here is the basic idea in R.

```
run_splitstr.R

command ="python“

Note the single + double quotes in the string (needed if paths have spaces)
path2script='"path/to your script/splitstr.py"'

Build up args in a vector
string ="3523462---12413415---4577678---7967956---5456439"
pattern ="---"
args = c(string, pattern)

# Add path to script as first arg
allArgs = c(path2script, args)

output = system2(command, args=allArgs, stdout=TRUE)

print(paste("The Substrings are:\n", output))
```

This works well on my machine, but I have to pass dataframes as separate csv files between Python and R, and I am worried that this won't be acceptable in order for this to become a package.

Is there any better way than this for a Windows system? Or is this whole idea futile.

Thanks!

Comment: The feather package was supposed to do this.  For me on Windows it works great in R but not in Python.  So I think for some people it may be a good option, for Windows users it may not be fully operational yet.

Comment: Feather is better than CSVs, but really you should probably use rPython or rpy2 and write everything in R or in Python. Better, learn now to make things fast in R.